# How to Fetch Webpage Through TCP socket using HTTP Request in JAVA

Tags: java, html, http, sockets, tcpclient

My college assignment is to fetch a web page from any web server by URL using a TCP socket and HTTP `GET` request.

I am not getting an `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` response from any server.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
public class DCCN042 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner inpt = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter URL: ");
                String url = inpt.next();
                TCPConnect(url); 
            }
   public static void TCPConnect(String url) {
        try {
            String hostname = new URL(url).getHost();
            System.out.println("Loading contents of Server: " + hostname);
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
            String ip = ia.getHostAddress();
            System.out.println(ip + " is IP Adress for  " + hostname);
            String path = new URL(url).getPath();
            System.out.println("Requested Path on the server: " + path);
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 80);
            // Create input and output streams to read from and write to the server
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            // Follow the HTTP protocol of GET <path> HTTP/1.0 followed by an empty line
            if (hostname ! = url) {
                //Request Line
                out.println("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1");
                out.println("Host: " + hostname);
                //Header Lines
                out.println("User-Agent: Java/13.0.2");
                out.println("Accept-Language: en-us");
                out.println("Accept: */*");
                out.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                out.println("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
                // Blank Line
                out.println();
            } else {
                //Request Line
                out.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
                out.println("Host: " + hostname);
                //Header Lines
                out.println("User-Agent: Java/13.0.2");
                out.println("Accept-Language: en-us");
                out.println("Accept: */*");
                out.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                out.println("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
                // Blank Line
                out.println();
            }
            // Read data from the server until we finish reading the document
            String line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = in.readLine();
            }
            // Close our streams
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid URl");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I create a TCP socket and pass the IP address that I receive from `InetAddress.getHostAddress()` and port `80` for the web server, and use `getPath()` and `getHost()` to separate the path and hostname from the URL, and use the same path and hostname in the HTTP `GET` request.

The response from the server:

```
Enter URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015868/java-simple-http-get-request-using-tcp-sockets
    Loading contents of Server: stackoverflow.com
    151.101.65.69 is IP Adress for  stackoverflow.com
    Requested Path on the server: /questions/33015868/java-simple-http-get-request-using-tcp-sockets
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015868/java-simple-http-get-request-using-tcp-sockets
    x-request-guid: 5f2af765-40c2-49ca-b9a1-daa321373682
    feature-policy: microphone 'none'; speaker 'none'
    content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Mon, 27 Dec 2021 15:00:17 GMT
    Via: 1.1 varnish
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Served-By: cache-qpg1263-QPG
    X-Cache: MISS
    X-Cache-Hits: 0
    X-Timer: S1640617217.166650,VS0,VE338
    Vary: Fastly-SSL
    X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
    Set-Cookie: prov=149aa0ef-a3a6-8001-17c1-128d6d4b7273; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
    
    0
```

My requirement is to get the HTML source code of this webpage, and an `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` response.

Comment: I hope this helps https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/SiebInstWIN/SiebInstCOM_InstSWSE19.html#:~:text=the%20Web%20Server.-,The%20default%20HTTP%20and%20HTTPS%20ports%20for%20the%20Web,port%2080%20and%20443%2C%20respectively.

Comment: Also, HTTPS is not using plain sockets to communicate. So you should rather use `SSLSocket` for HTTPS or find a site that doesn't have HTTPS.

Comment: @geobreze, I was not using SSL Socket and hitting 'https'. Thank you it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a plain `Socket` with a hardcoded port `80`. This means that, independently of using a `http` or `https` url in your input, you are requesting via the unsecure protocol `http`.

In this situation, the server is telling you, as Samuel L. Jackson would say "*hey mf! you are trying to reach me through an f unsecure protocol, HTTP. Use a secure one mf, the f HTTPS.*", and so, it responds with [301](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) (which just means "use this url, not the original one"), with the `Location` header pointing to the correct URL, the `https` one.

So apparently the `301` `Location` is the same URL, but it's not, because in your code you are hardcoding `http`, and the server response is redirecting to `https`.

To make your code work with `https`, instead of a plain `Socket` use this:

```java
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(ia, 443);
```

**Do note** that I'm not using the `ip`, because for `https` you need that the certificate corresponds to the domain, if you use the IP you will get a `CertificateExpiredException`.

Now, whether to use `Socket` or `SSLSocket` is something that you will have to manage programatically depending on the user input.